# Access active tab index value in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple Jquery tab in my html page and I want to use active tab index so I can display content specific to the tab based on index value.
I tried below,

> < div id="tabs-1" ng-model="name.b" ng-value="true" >
>   < div id="tabs-2" ng-model="name.b" ng-value="false" >

When I use ng-model and ng-value combination in this div tab its not working. I mean im unable read the ng-value in using scope.

> data : {
>                 'name' : $scope.name,
>                 'result': $scope.name.b
>                                 }

TIA

Comment: ng-value is only applicable to those elements with a `value` attribute - namely HTMLInputElements.

Comment: ok. in that case. how can I get active index value in my scope

Comment: The AngularJS way is to write a directive and do the DOM parsing there. Then pass that value back. In a directive you can use either the jQuery UI Tabs API, you can look for the `ui-tabs-active` class name, or you can set a listener for the active state change. Any or all three of these should be done in a custom directive and pass the value back to your controller.

Comment: What? `ngModel` and `ngValue` on a div??? Maybe you should try `ng-bind`